# What is a 'question record', in particular a positive one?

Tags: support, badges

The description of the [`curious' badge reads](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/200/curious): "Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record". What does the last part mean?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291457/viewing-question-record.

Comment: I'll add that this is explained also in the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397). And on meta.SE you can find a few other related posts, such as: [How is a “positive question record” calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290545) And there is also this related feature request: [Give users a way to see their “Positive Question Record” score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I never thought of looking up one level higher, in the meta.stackexchange, rather than here in meta.mo and the mo-helpcenter!

Comment: In fact, quite often basic information and useful links are included also in the tag-info here on meta. In this case, the first link in my comment is also included in the [badges tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/badges/info) on Mathoverflow Meta. (Still it is probably useful to have this question also here - it is quite likely that other users might look for this information here on meta.MO; in which case they'll find your question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If half the total number of questions asked (including deleted ones) is greater than or equal to the sum total of (1) the number of deleted questions, (2) the number of questions with negative net score, (3) the number of closed questions, then the account has a positive question record. Note: the numbers of (1), (2), (3) *are counted separately*. Thus a question which has negative net score and was closed and deleted is counted three times (!). This is explained in the post that jeq linked to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291457/viewing-question-record.

Comment: Then it's better not to delete a question