# Would undeleting questions increase the positive question record?

Tags: support

I came to know that to have a positive question record the total number of questions (including deleted ones) must be at least double the sum of (deleted, downvoted, and closed) questions.

If a question is deleted and downvoted then it counts as -2, while if deleted, downvoted and closed then it counts as -3.

So, if one has a lot of deleted questions that are also downvoted, then undeleting them would increase the positive question record even if they get further downvoted?

Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/260547 ; undeleted questions can later be deleted automatically, so undeleting may not be that useful.

Comment: Related, here on MO Meta: [What is a 'question record', in particular a positive one?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3602/183188)